# Odd Behaviour with Session - Session has a new Id for each Controller instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc 5 web application with the following controllers :
HomeController -> AccoutController -> PanelController

```cs
public abstract class BasicController : Controller
{
    private const string CURRENT_USER = "CurrentUser";
    public IUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return Session[CURRENT_USER] as IUser;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[CURRENT_USER] = value;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        logger.Debug(string.Format("Controller {0} SessionId {1}", 
            filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name, 
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID));
    }
}
```

```cs
public class HomeController : BasicController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(this.CurrentUser == null)
            Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Account", null, Request.Url.Scheme), true);

        var model = new HomeViewModel()
        {
            CurrentUser = this.CurrentUser
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class AccountController : BasicController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LogOnViewModel model = new LogOnViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = SomeClassThatConnectsToADAndOtherStuff.GetUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if(user == null)
                throw new Exception();
            this.CurrentUser = user;
            logger.Debug("User is authenticated");
            Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Panel", null, Request.Url.Scheme), true);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = Role.BIGUSER)]
public partial class PanelController : BasicController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PanelViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string CURRENT_USER = "CurrentUser";
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        logger.Debug(string.Format("AuthorizeAttribute Path {0} SessionId {1}", httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath, httpContext.Session.SessionID));
        IUser user = httpContext.Session[CURRENT_USER] as IUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            logger.Debug("Session[CURRENT_USER] is null > go to login");
            return false;
        }
        string[] rolesSplit = this.Roles.Split(',');
        if (rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The issue is that for each time a `Controller` is instantiated the `Session` object has a new `SessionID` and `Session[CURRENT_USER]` is never persisted.

Logs

```
[1] INFO  MvcApplicationAssembly - Application start...
[7] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - Controller HomeController SessionId ano4nre1etv0pbikirmjzk0w
[7] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - Controller AccountController SessionId ej3x4hbd01vzkbuu2ckuafuw
[8] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - Controller AccountController SessionId 20xwfutyk0atgxbxdpbegv2h
[8] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - User is authenticated
[7] DEBUG HelperAssembly         - AuthorizeAttribute Path / SessionId att3k4urjzdls2oc2r4h2clq
[7] DEBUG HelperAssembly         - Session[CURRENT_USER] is null > go to login
[8] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - Controller AccountController SessionId xwtlzhebnr1xmyld2otiw2w1
[8] DEBUG MvcApplicationAssembly - Controller HomeController SessionId kr5hwm001pp4ppkf2b0lvmjv
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Chrotenise yes this is the actual code (modified class names only). `CURRENT_USER` is always `"CurrentUser"` I don't think the `Session` keys are the issue here since the `HttpContextBase.Session` is not the same when redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your sessions are not being saved in a cookie correctly or your time-out window is too low.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)

I quote the pertinent part:

> Session Identifiers
>
> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
> using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
> ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
> examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
> value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
> value for that session is sent to the browser with the response.
>
> By default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie. However, you can
> also configure the application to store SessionID values in the URL
> for a "cookieless" session.
>
> A session is considered active as long as requests continue to be made
> with the same SessionID value. If the time between requests for a
> particular session exceeds the specified time-out value in minutes,
> the session is considered expired. Requests made with an expired
> SessionID value result in a new session.